# Require Path Renders a Special Character

Tags: php

When I try and require:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "\master\vendor\autoload.php";
require_once($path);
```

I receive this instead:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\masterendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

For some reason a special character is rendered. I am running on Windows IIS with PHP7.

Comment: Backslashes in double quotes should be espaced (by another backslash), because the can introduce an escape sequence, like \n or \t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape backslashes, or use a single quoted string. `\v` expands into a vertical tab character.

```
$path .= "\\master\\vendor\\autoload.php";

$path .= '\master\vendor\autoload.php';
```

See [the PHP documentation on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for details.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can either use escaped \ or /.
So this will work:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/master/vendor/autoload.php";
require_once($path);
```

Comment: PHP does a lot of things behind the scenes